# Matching PCI and Thunderbolt devices

Tags: linux, gpu, pci, sysfs

Is there a reliable way to find which PCI devices (eg. video card) are connected via a particular Thunderbolt device (eg. eGPU enclosure, Dock) on a Linux system?

**Context**
In my particular use-case, I'm mostly interested in detecting and identifying connected TB3 eGPUs. I am able to detect video devices based on PCI, but being able to match them with the Thunderbolt Device through which they are connected, would help me to solve the following problems:

1. Reliably detect whether a specific video device is an eGPU
2. Distinguish multiple eGPUs from each other, even if they are the same vendor/product, by identifying their eGPU enclosures (via TB UUID)

I'm currently parsing information about PCI and Thunderbolt devices from `/sys/bus/pci/devices` and `/sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/` respectively.

---

**Failed attempt: Using the PCI bus hierarchy**
Unfortunately, the PCI bus hierarchy doesn't seem to be very helpful in that matter.
I can map thunderbolt devices to a PCI device called `Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI`. **But**, both Thunderbolt devices (if two are connected) point to this same device. Furthermore, the PCI devices for the video cards (eGPU) are children of another PCI bus, making it seem as it is not possible to directly map the PCI video devices (eGPU) to their corresponding Thunderbolt device (eGPU enclosure).

Although I don't really understand the meaning of it yet, the following paragraph I found in the kernel documentation seems to somewhat confirm this observation (?).

> A Thunderbolt host controller comprises a number of PCIe hotplug ports and an NHI device to manage the PCIe switch. On resume from system sleep, the NHI device needs to re-establish PCI tunnels to attached devices before the hotplug ports can resume. If the hotplug ports were children of the NHI, this resume order would automatically be enforced by the PM core, **but unfortunately they’re aunts**.
>
> – https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/device_link.html?highlight=thunderbolt#examples

**Resources**
I am not familiar with the kernel and discovered most of these things by directly inspecting my system and drawing conclusions from that. If anyone can provide me with links to useful resources about Linux/PCI/Thunderbolt, that might already help me a lot. I'm listing some links here for completeness, because they were useful in my learning process.

- [Linux PCI Bus Subsystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/PCI/index.html) (kernel.org)
- [Rules on how to access information in sysfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/sysfs-rules.html) (kernel.org)
- [Accessing PCI device resources through sysfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/PCI/sysfs-pci.html) (kernel.org)
- [PCI configuration Space - Standardized registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space#Standardized_registers) (wikipedia.org)
- [PCI - PCI Device Structure - Common Header Fields](https://wiki.osdev.org/PCI#Common_Header_Fields) (osdev.org)
- [Linux Device Drivers - Chapter 12. PCI Drivers](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch12.html) (Book)

Comment: "Reliable" as in "works for all hardware, no matter which PCI card connected to which thunderbolt hardware"? My gut feeling is "doesn't exist", because there's no standard way hardware is required to do this, and ever hardware vendor can do it differently.

Comment: Exactly. In my case, I'd be satisfied by only finding a solution working with PCI video cards specifically, but I don't think there is any big difference there, because it would still need to be vendor agnostic and work with any video card and any eGPU enclosure.
I've now started going through the kernel code for PCI and Thunderbolt and I am hoping to understand enough of it to at least get some hints from there.